# Show the scrollbar on right side browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This website (stackoverflow.com) has a scrollbar embedded in the right side of the browser. 
I want to have the same thing in my asp.net webforms site.  I can get a scrollbar inside the browser but I have not been able to figure out how to make the scrollbar work the same as the one on this site.

Comment: what do you mean " work the same as the one on this site"?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely all you need is to simply apply a [`overflow-y: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) rule to your page. By default in most browsers, the scrollbar will appear only when scrolling (as is the case with SO). Checkout [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/) for further discussion to figure out what you need to do.

If unsure how to add CSS to your webforms site, you can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444643/asp-net-web-forms-master-page-css-file).

Comment: Thanks, as I wrote in my answer above it was related to overflow settings.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the the problem was that I had the "overflow: auto" set for all the controls in the site.  Because of this there was never a reason for the scroll bar in the side of the browser to become active.  Now that the controls don't produce there own scroll bar the browser does.